# read.csv vs read.table - difficulty in comparing results

Tags: r, csv

I have a tab separated data with a column containing addresses including commas in the addresses.

I am using read.table to import a data into R, however my colleague used read.csv with sep="\t" to do the same and we both end up with different number of rows in the imported data frame.

Also, when I import the data in Excel, I get the same number of records as read.csv with sep="\t".

What is the most concrete way i can verify which import and number of records is the correct one?

Please let me know what details I can add here to help answer the question.

Comment: You could post a few lines of your csv on https://gist.github.com/ and give the link and the few lines of codes to import the csv. The `sep` argument is important but you may also consider `quote` and `dec`. Another solution would be to use `read_delim` in the `readr` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the help files for the two functions via `?read.table` (that'll show both). You'll see that `read.csv` is just `read.table` with some of the arguments set to different defaults.

One of those arguments is `header`. In `read.table` with `sep="\t"`, try also using `header=TRUE`.

If that doesn't work, do the following: `read.table('file.txt', header=TRUE, sep="\t", quote="\"", dec=".", fill=TRUE, comment.char=""`. That code should give the exact same result as `read.csv`, because I just set all the arguments to those used by `read.csv`. You can then begin by changing some of those arguments back to the `read.table` default (by not specifying them) to figure out which argument is causing the difference between `read.csv` and `read.table` for your data.frame (remember, more than one argument could be causing the difference). I can easily see ways that the `header`, `sep`, `quote`, `comment.char`, and `fill` arguments could affect the number of rows in the output. I can't imagine how `dec` would have this effect, but I wouldn't be surprised if it matters.

As a rule, I tend to expect that different input = different output, and when different input = same output, I consider that to be exceptional. The functions you're using are similar, but they're differences are different ways of interpreting the text file, so I would *expect* them to yield different results. Which is "right" is not a matter of one of the functions preforming correctly and the other incorrectly, it's a matter of the user understanding what they are doing in relation to the input.

Comment: i fully agree and understand. i am trying this out now. however, what would be the best way to confirm which worked correctly, i mean the raw file has 400k records, one can't check what is the exact number of records and which of read.table or read.csv did it correctly. any ideas?

Comment: I would use somethign like `t1 <- read.csv()`, `t2 <- read.table()`, `dim(t1)`, `dim(t2)`. Does that make sense? Think about what set of arguments causes them to give different answers, and the type of csv you're reading. When my data files have a "comment" column, I have to be very careful about how various character are interpreted (in particular, the `comment` argument is useful). Sorry if I came off as pedantic, it wasn't clear to me if you considered it a "bug" that `read.aable` was giving a surprising result.

Comment: To be clear, when there is a comment column, consider what happens when someone has entered "sunny warm, boat needs repair, entered data with a #2 pencil"! The "#" is considered a "comment" sometimes, and the commas could be interpreted as column delimiters. (I cant confirm what exactly would happen here, but I think you can see my point that when there is a portion of the text file where the entries were typed casually by humans, you have to be careful)

Comment: it wasn't pedantic. i didn't consider it a bug. (1) i didn't know why there was a difference and it is clear to me now, i used your suggestion and now i get same record count with quote="\"". (2) how do i ensure practically that it was correct before quote="\"" or after ' quote="\"" ' ?

Comment: I would do `head(t1)` and `tail(t1)`, then do the same with `t2`. I would hope that there would be visible differences in the R output. I would then ask myself which made more sense (to me, as a person who has prior expectations for what the data should look like), and go with whichever approach seemed to interpreted the data file the way I wanted. I'd be willing to bet that using `quote="\""` is what you want, b/c I'm pretty sure that would prevent `sunny,boat` in a column from being interpreted as two columns of `sunny` for one and `boat` for the other.

Comment: understand. i believe that solves my problem now. thanks for your answer and comments.